# How can I "save" variables client side so I can use it during some other java script event?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

This is a .html page.

Kendo Auto Complete has a SELECT functionality:

```
select: function(e)
            {
                valid = true;
                if (e.item == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                nameId = DataItem.NameId;
                personId = DataItem.PersonId;
            }
```

Basically what the above does is captures some variable values for me.

This is working fine.

The issue is, I want to use the variables `nameId` and `personId` in some other function and event later.

What would be the correct way to "save" these variables?

These variables will be used as parameters on a POST request later.

Comment: You can set a cookie with js. here's a sample: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/settinga.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store locally on client side:

```
localStorage.setItem("nameId",nameId);
localStorage.setItem("personId",personId);
```

Retrieve their values:

```
nameId=localStorage.getItem("nameId");
personId=localStorage.getItem("personId");
```

Comment: Are you really quoting w3fools? localStorage should only be accessed via `getItem` and `setItem`. All other methods might work, but are not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use global variables (although this method should only be done as a last resort)

otherwise, javascript is going to assume the scope of your variables to last only the length of the function. If you want the scope to extend beyond the function, then declare them outside the function like so:

```
var date_item = null
function doSomething(){
    date_item = b
}


function doSomethingElse(){
    alert(data_item)
}
```

to use a global variable, just dont use the prefix "var" in front of your variable declaration

```
var date_item = null // local
date_item = null // global
```